# After registering user, req.isAuthenticated is returning false

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have done this in a few apps and I dont know what is happening here that is not working, when I go to my login page and login a user, then I have a logged in user  can work with. But in my register route after I register the user I call passport.authenticate yet the user doesnt get authenticated and I have no user to work with, I dont know what is wrong. I also wrote the register post route in callback format without async/await no difference. And the users get added to my database, so they are registered.

Here is my code:

```
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
   res.render('register')
});

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try{
       var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
       await User.register(newUser, req.body.password);
       await passport.authenticate('local');
       console.log("The user is authenticated: " + req.isAuthenticated())
       res.redirect('/');
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

The console.log returns false.

User model:

```
var mongoose              = require('mongoose'),
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:     String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Register page:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<h1>Please Sign-Up</h1>

<form action='register' method='POST'>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='username'>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type='password' name='password'>

    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>


<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

in my app.js file:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
  console.log("Current user is: " + req.user)
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well firstly, you are misusing `passport.authenticate` here - this function returns the correct connect/express-compatible middleware for the strategy type you pass, in your case `local`. So in actual fact, if you really did want to use it like this you would need to call it like `passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, next)`....however, I don't think you really want to be doing that.

You have three separate operations here

1. register the user
2. authenticate the user
3. redirect the user

Which to me should happen as three separate middlewares i.e.

```
const registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = new User({ username });
    await User.register(user, password);
    return next();
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
}

router.post('/register', 
  registerUser, // register user in the DB
  passport.authenticate('local'), // authenticate user credentials
  (req, res) => res.redirect('/') // redirect user
)
```

So just to break down what's happening here, when the `/register` route is hit, it will first attempt to register the user via the `registerUser` middleware. Assuming all goes well here, we call `next` to invoke the next middleware which is our passport local strategy (the credentials will still be in `req.body` from the initial request). Then finally, if our authentication is successful, passport will invoke the next available middleware which is our redirect call.

Comment: Hi James, thank you very much for the answer I was really stuck there. I am new to webdev learned from a online course, they actually taught the passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, next) method which is what I have been using and actually tried it here and didn't work, usually does though maybe I did something wrong? Could you please tell me why you said I shouldn't use that method??? Also if you could I don't understand why what I was doing wasn't working seems like it should, could you please explain it to me, I really want to learn and get better at this. Thanks so much

Comment: @Jack well as explained in the answer, `passport.authenticate` is specifically designed to work as middleware, you can of course use it directly however it's written in a way that it can be plugged into an express route (as shown in my answer).

Comment: is there any reason why you make a const registerUser instead of just making it a function called registerUser?

Comment: @Jack in this scenario, other than being able to use the arrow syntax, no - `async function registerUser(...)` would work just the same.

Comment: Thanks! went over your answer a few times got clearer!